# How to fix "AttributeError: 'OAuth2ConsumerBlueprint' object has no attribute 'get'" error

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0, basecamp

I am trying to create an application which links the Basecamp API.
I am using the flask-dance provided custom blueprint.
https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#module-flask_dance.contrib.facebook

I am trying to redirect my app to the basecamp login page but it states this error: 
AttributeError: 'OAuth2ConsumerBlueprint' object has no attribute 'get'

How to fix this error?

```
    from flask import Flask, url_for, request, jsonify, session, redirect
    from flask_dance.consumer import OAuth2ConsumerBlueprint
    from flask_oauthlib.client import OAuth

    app = Flask(__name__)
    oauth = OAuth()
    basecamp = OAuth2ConsumerBlueprint(
        "basecamp", __name__,
        client_id="",
        client_secret="",
        base_url="",
        token_url="https://launchpad.37signals.com/authorization/token",
        authorization_url='https://launchpad.37signals.com/authorization/new?type=web_server',
        )
        app.register_blueprint(basecamp, url_prefix='/basecamp_login')


        @app.route('/basecamp')
        def basecamp_login():
            if not basecamp.authorized:
                return redirect(url_for('basecamp.base_url'))
            account_info = basecamp.get('/email_address')

            if account_info.ok:
                account_info_json = account_info.json()
                return '<h1>Your basecamp email address is{}'.format()

        if __name__ == '__main__':

            app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

As it states in [the documentation for custom Flask-Dance providers](https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#custom), you need to refer to the `session` attribute on the blueprint in order to make HTTP requests. In your case, `basecamp.get('/email_address')` is wrong, because `basecamp` is the `OAuth2ConsumerBlueprint` object. You should call `basecamp.session.get('/email_address')` instead.